# How to set window transparency in Kubuntu?

Tags: 22.04, transparency

How does one set the window transparency with <kbd>ALT</kbd> + mouse wheel in Kubuntu 22.04?

I can no longer find that setting anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

- In **System Settings > Workspace Behavior > Desktop Effects**, uncheck *"Translucency"*.
- In **System Settings > Window Management > Window Behavior**, click the *"Window Actions"* tab.

  - In the *"Inner Window, Titlebar and Frame Actions"* section, set *"Modifier key"* to <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and next to *"Mouse wheel"* choose *"Change opacity"* from the drop down menu.